# how to perform a post through chrome extention?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, http-post

How can I perform a post through the chrome extention, lets say I want to send the current tab page title to a webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do POST XHRs from chrome extensions to any URL, as long as you have host permissions defined in your manifest. See these [docs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html).

Answer (score 0):

In a chrome extension the best way to try and do what i think you want is via a content script see  [documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) a word of warning however pinging your server with a POST request every time someone with your extension installed opens a web page is going to be extremely heavy going on your servers especially if you have a lot of installs. A possible solution is to use the content script to keep tally of the sites a user visits and save this data in a HTML5 database (wich chrome supports) then using background.html sending the data at given intervals in bulk with an AJAX request, this will significantly cut down the number of times your server is pinged.